# Swiper typings to angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, swiper.js, typescript-typings

Im trying to import typings for swiper to angular2.

I've installed swiper and its typings via npm, but in my component when I include swiper

```
import { Swiper } from 'swiper';
```

atom shows error:

> path/../@types/swiper/index.d.ts is not a module

Is it possible that the typings are badly declared or is it my fault?

Comment: For me, using VSCode, every time I install new typings, I need to restart or else I get the same error as you're getting. Pretty tedious.  Not sure if it's the same with Atom

Comment: have you tried change index.d.ts to main.d.ts?

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to module errors the 1.2.3 is:

1. save the file (continue if persists)
2. close the file tab, reopen the file tab
3. restart the IDE
4. run tsc to see if it also has a problem
5. check the index.d.ts for validness (case by case)
6. if all else fails, delete the typings and stub your own 'empty module' in, say, index.d.ts in your src/ folder